# Making a button element submit

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Using ASP.NET, how do I make this button tag submit my ASP.NET form when clicked:

```
<button>Submit</button>
```

I'd like it to do a post back just like a regular asp.net server control button would work. I'd prefer a jquery way to do it if possible.

Comment: Take a look at the `__doPostBack` function that gets inserted by asp.net controls in the page body. Emulate this behavior. I'm not sure if you are asking for the server tag or if you want to take a plain html tag and modify it to do a postback with js/jquery.

Comment: @ryan -- I want to do the latter...take a plain html tag and modify it to do a postback with jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('form').submit(); 
});
```

On button click, it will find the closest form (which will be the parent) and submit it by passing the form to the `action` where you can access the values through your defined method; either `get` or `post`.

I think this is what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use:

```
<input type="Submit" />
```

Or using jQuery you can use:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        $('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you use javascript when you have links, or divs, or other elements that can not do post back.

In your case  the `<button>Submit</button>` in html5 renders a submit button that if you click it, you just submit the form and that all you need.

The extra asp.net controls have some more functionality and communication with the code behind, but for the submit of the form, any submit button ether that one, ether the classic `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` can do what you ask as they are.